# How can I select a part from a big string starting in point A and ending in point B

Tags: c#, regex, string, select

My string is:

```
[...]
<div class="threads">
<a href="/adgagshsdh_t_54654321654" title="Title 2">
<a href="/adgagsdfdfhsdh_t_44654321654" title="Title 3">
<a href="/adgagsdfhsdh_t_54321654" title="Title 4">
<a href="/adgagsdfhsdfhsdh_t_14654321654" title="Title 5">
[...etc]
</div>
[...]
```

I want to take everything out except for **_t_54654321654** and then after that everything but **54654321654**.

Final string should look like this

```
54654321654
```

I tried with **`indexOf`** but didn't really work.

I tried searching but I didn't know how exactly to describe what I was trying to do.

Comment: What's your final out put?? Which portion do u want from it?

Comment: Do you want in **`sql server`**?

Comment: is that html you are parsing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string whatYouNeed = "/adgadgdfhdsdfgsadfgdsg_t_54654321654".Split('_').Last();
```

Or

```
string whatYouNeed = "<a href=\"/adgadgdfhdsdfgsadfgdsg_t_54654321654\" title=\"Title\">"
    .Split('_')
    .Last()
    .Split(new string[] {"\""},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .First();
```

But If you want to work with HTML content you better use 
[Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

[Check this question which some what similar to this and by using html agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497673/html-agility-pack-parsing-an-href-tag)

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.Load("test.html");
var link = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                  .Descendants("a")
                  .First(); // assume it is First link tag what you need

string hrefValue = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
string whatYouNeed = hrefValue.Split('_').Last();
```

**Answers to your comments**

> but what if I have the source code inside an string and not in a
>   test.html document?

You can load the html as below

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

> Also there's dozens of `"<a href"'s` with different numbers in them in
>   the source code, I don't need a specific one, just one of them.

```
var links = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                      .Descendants("a").ToList();
```

above will return all the links in the page you can get any item you want like `links[1]` or `links[3]` etc ...

Comment: this won't work in case op try's to parse the complete html using split..first op should get string out of `href` and then he can use the above code

Comment: Hm... but what if I have the source code inside an string and not in a test.html document? Also there's dozens of "<a href"'s with different numbers in them in the source code, I don't need a specific one, just one of them, updated OP a little bit for hopefully better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try it by the sub string method

Like

```
string sub = mainString.Substring(startPosition, endPosition);
```

Comment: Already tried with substring: "Too many characters in character literal" error

Comment: U got this error because there are too many string sign("") in your main string.

Comment: Hm well my whole string is a page source code (html) I'm getting it through string s = reader.ReadToEnd().ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  Regex rgx = new Regex("^.+?_t_([^\"]+?)\".+?$");
  string result = rgx.Replace(yourString, "$1");
```

Explanation: It matches characters from the begining of the string using `^` and moves till `_t_` and then sub-matches in `$1` anything till `"` and then `"` and then anything till end `$`.

The whole string is replaced by the sub-match `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        int index = s.LastIndexOf('_') + 1;
        string t = s.Substring(index, s.Length - index);
```