# How do I get href from a tag in a table?

Tags: c#, web-services, html-agility-pack

I have a webmethod like,

```
public List<List<string>> HelloWorld() {

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    string page = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.deu.edu.tr/DEUWeb/Guncel/v2_index_cron.html");

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(page);

        List<List<string>> table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table")
        .Descendants("tr")
        .Skip(1)
        .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
        .ToList();

    return table;
}
```

I've got the information inside the table but I want to get also `<a href="Link">` link information of the table.

What should I add to the method? I need both information at the same time.

### HTML

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <img/>
     </td>
     <td>
        <a href="what I want">Text</a>
     </td>
   </tr>
    .....
</table>
```

Comment: What does *link info* mean?

Comment: I mean there is a link such as "www.google.com" written in href part. I want to get that also.

Comment: Href part of what? You need to show an example of the HTML your parsing. Href isn't a valid attribute of a a table.

Comment: <a href= " some link" class="" > Some Information about link </a>

I took the information from this code, but I want to get the link belong to the information.

Comment: Please just put the HTML in next time. An image is not helpful.

Comment: Thank you that's what I want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Agility pack: parsing an href tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497673/html-agility-pack-parsing-an-href-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery, something like this:

```
<a href="https://google.com" class="demo">Click me</a>
<script>
alert($('.demo').attr('href'));
</script>
```

Comment: I need it in C# not in JavaScript and I need an addition to my code if possible..