# How to get href value in using HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: html-agility-pack

How do I retrieve the values of HREF Tag using HTML AgilityPack?

```
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-24 businessCapsule--ctas">
            <a href="http://www.xyz.coo.in" data-tracking="FLE:WL:CLOSED" class="businessCapsule--ctaItem" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener">
            <div class="icon icon-Business-website" title="Website"></div> Website</a>
            <div class="businessCapsule--telephone">
            <div class="business--telephone business--telephone-noMarginRight">
            <span class="icon icon-phone business--telephoneIcon"></span>
            <div class="business--telephoneContent">
            <span class="business--telephonePrefix">Tel</span>
            <span class="business--telephoneNumber" itemprop="telephone">154 75 695 451 </span>
```

Comment: grammatical fixes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Agility pack: parsing an href tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497673/html-agility-pack-parsing-an-href-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `a.Attributes.First().Value;`
Where "a" is the HtmlNode that you want